# Is there "man" command equivalent in python3 to view the use of methods?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any "man" command equivalent in python3 to view the use of certain built in methods?

Answer (score 1):

You can use built-in function "help".
You can use it in your interpreter like this:

```
 help (int)
```

You'll find this answer:

```
Help on class int in module builtins:

class int(object)
 |  int(x=0) -> integer
 |  int(x, base=10) -> integer
 |
 |  Convert a number or string to an integer, or return 0 if no arguments
 |  are given.  If x is a number, return x.__int__().  For floating point
 ...
```

You can find the documentation for help function here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help